# How to count the number of occurences of an element with scala/spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I had a file that contained a list of elements like this

```
00|905000|20160125204123|79644809999||HGMTC|1||22|7905000|56321647569|||34110|I||||||250995210056537|354805064211510||56191|||38704||A|||11|V|81079681404134|5||||SE|||G|144|||||||||||||||Y|b00534589.huawei_anadyr.20151231184912||1|||||79681404134|0|||+@@+1{79098509982}2{2}3{2}5{79644809999}6{0000002A7A5AC635}7{79681404134}|20160125|
```

Through a series of steps, I managed to convert it to a list of elements like this

```
(902996760100000,CompactBuffer(6, 5, 2, 2, 8, 6, 5, 3))
```

Where **905000** and **902996760100000** are keys and **6, 5, 2, 2, 8, 6, 5, 3** are values. Values can be numbers from 1 to 8. Are there any ways to count number of occurences of these values using spark, so the result looks like this?

```
(902996760100000, 0_1, 2_2, 1_3, 0_4, 2_5, 2_6, 0_7, 1_8)
```

I could do it with if else blocks and staff, but that won't be pretty, so I wondered if there are any instrumets I could use in scala/spark.

This is my code.

```
class ScalaJob(sc: SparkContext) {
  def run(cdrPath: String) : RDD[(String, Iterable[String])] = {
    //pass the file
    val fileCdr = sc.textFile(cdrPath);

    //find values in every raw cdr
    val valuesCdr = fileCdr.map{
      dataRaw =>
      val p = dataRaw.split("[|]",-1)
      (p(1), ScalaJob.processType(ScalaJob.processTime(p(2)) + "_" + p(32)))
    }
    val x = valuesCdr.groupByKey()
    return x
  }
```

Any advice on optimizing it would be appreciated. I'm really new to scala/spark.

Comment: Just a piece of advice, get rid of the code and information that are not relevant to the scope of your question, it makes your question less readable.

Comment: You could look at the canonical [word count example](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Scala is a type-safe language and so is Spark's RDD API - so it's highly recommended to *use* the type system instead of going around it by "encoding" everything into Strings.

So I'll suggest a solution that creates an `RDD[(String, Seq[(Int, Int)])]` (with second item in tuple being a sequence of (ID, count) tuples) and not a `RDD[(String, Iterable[String])]` which seems less useful.

Here's a simple function that counts the occurrences of 1 to 8 in a given `Iterable[Int]`:

```
def countValues(l: Iterable[Int]): Seq[(Int, Int)] = {
  (1 to 8).map(i => (i, l.count(_ == i)))
}
```

You can use `mapValues` with this function (place the function in the object for serializability, like you did with the rest) on an `RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])]` to get the result:

```
valuesCdr.groupByKey().mapValues(ScalaJob.countValues)
```

The entire solution can then be simplified a bit:

```
class ScalaJob(sc: SparkContext) {
  import ScalaJob._

  def run(cdrPath: String): RDD[(String, Seq[(Int, Int)])] = {
    val valuesCdr = sc.textFile(cdrPath)
      .map(_.split("\\|"))
      .map(p => (p(1), processType(processTime(p(2)), p(32))))

    valuesCdr.groupByKey().mapValues(countValues)
  }  
}

object ScalaJob {
  val dayParts = Map((6 to 11) -> 1, (12 to 18) -> 2, (19 to 23) -> 3, (0 to 5) -> 4)

  def processTime(s: String): Int = {
    val hour = DateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")).getHourOfDay
    dayParts.filterKeys(_.contains(hour)).values.head
  }

  def processType(dayPart: Int, s: String): Int = s match {
    case "S" => 2 * dayPart - 1
    case "V" => 2 * dayPart
  }

  def countValues(l: Iterable[Int]): Seq[(Int, Int)] = {
    (1 to 8).map(i => (i, l.count(_ == i)))
  }
}
```